# Security using MongoDB db.find() and Express 4.0 req.params

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Is it safe to build a MongoDb query with the `db.find()` method by passing the `req.params` object?

Are there any security issues?

Example:

```
app.get('/trip/:id', function(req, res) {
    Trip.find(req.params, function(err, user) {
        if(err) return err;
        return res.json({ user);
    });
});
```

Assuming the params object does contain the id value it would look like this:

```
{ id: '564a8e0cdc41d7736c70df0a' }
```

Are there any security issues with MongoDb in doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Database querying security issues are related to how much freedom you give the query and how much information the query returns. If you're looking up an item by id, check it by id, if you're looking for it by another key, check it by that key.

This isn't limited to mongodb but applies all the same, just ensure you lint responses and don't throw out superfluous information. From my experience, mongodb is no more at risk to query abuse than other databases.

I'd hope by the code you provided I couldn't goto `/users/:id` and get the entire document dumped.

Comment: Thanks Brod. No you would not be able to get the entire document dumped by visiting `/users/:id`. It is part of an API. Is it better than to be explicit and build the query with ID as the key and pull the value from `req.params.id`?

Comment: @JoseCarrillo sorry for the incredibly late reply, but, if your question merely relates the the `variable`'s name – without getting ridiculous, the more explicit the better imo, especially if your code is viewed / used by others.